# How to append an item to a list for a certain number of times?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to append `a` `n` times to a list, any shorter ways than this:

```
while n:
    list.append(a)
    n -= 1
```

Comment: `list.extend(a for _ in range(n))`?

Comment: Or just `lst.extend([a] * n)`. And don't call your variable `list`.

Comment: maybe `lst += [a]*n` is the shortest

Answer (score 3):

canonically, "do something `n` times" is accomplished with:

```
for _ in range(n):
    do_something()
```

However for this specific application, it's shorter to use `list.extend` and a list of `a`s.

```
original_list.extend([a] * n)
```

Comment: Which is fine assuming `a` is immutable. Otherwise, `extend(a for _ in range(n))` is preferred (or you run into a host of side effects).

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: That doesn't change anything unless you assume `a` can substitute for a more complex expression. Since the question is not about mutability, I would assume the OP knows what they're doing by appending the same object many times.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps with the range function if you knew n

```
for x in range(n):
    list.append(a)
```

Comment: Would you really do it this way when there are better ways to do it?

Comment: If the requirement dictated that the string be shorter than what OP originally posted I would have tried it at first. However; that said, I'm a Python novice working to learn more and seeing the list.extend that you posted in the comments above I would definitely take that route instead if I had known about it.